How to specfiy file/directory in file open dialog in a UI test using XCTest?
Using XCTest for UI testing a SwiftUI app, is it possible to specify a file/directory to be selected in a file open dialog? (Specifically, the one from a fileImporter call in SwiftUI; on both iOS and macOS.)
I’m trying to test a process where the user can tap a button which opens the file open dialog, select a file and tap the open button to complete the dialog, and then my app will do stuff with the user selected file (the results of which I evaluate in my test).
If that is not possible, what are alternative ways to cause my app to “open a specific file/directory” from a UI test?

This should be a unit test.

I’m trying to test that the UI ends up in the expected state when the user opens a file. I have comprehensive unit tests for the underlying “business logic”. What I need here is to test that the UI is performing as expected.
